# Getting very thin plots while plotting using plotlyjs in julia

Tags: plotly, julia, plotly.js

I'm trying to plot a random walk in Pluto after following a Julia tutorial but I'm getting a very thin graph (the height is very small).

[image: very thin graph using plotlyjs]

The code I'm running is `Plot(walk, Layout(yaxis_range=[-20,20], width=800, height=800))` and walk is a random walk and so is a list of integers like `[0,1,0,1,2,1,0,...,-17,-18,..]`.

I tried looking in many places and followed some recommended solutions for issues with plotly in julia like updating the package and installing the `GR` package but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The question is missing the information what IDE GUI you use. Is it Jupyter in a web browser?

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel The image has Pluto vibes. But question could have better code snippet (especially since code in post different from Pluto cell in image)

Comment: The problem might be the `width=800, height=800` parameters being for `Layout` or for `Plot` according to location of closing parenthesis. The right location would be inside the `Layout` call.

Comment: @DanGetz thst is why I asked - I usually know how to resolve such issues but this is hard when I have to guess what is on mind of the person asking the question. I need full info to replicate the issue.

Comment: Yes, it is pluto. I mentioned it in the question as well

Comment: @DanGetz Thanks, that appears to be the issue!

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comment, the problem might be that the `width=800, height=800` parameters are after `Layout` call and in `Plot` parameters, instead of being part of `Layout` parameters.

So the call should look like:

```
Plot(walk(100), Layout(yaxis_range=[-20,20], width=800, height=800))
```